# RelativeLayout not exceeding ScrollView height

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a ScrollView with a RelativeLayout as its child. This is all nested within a RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2fb136">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fpScrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fpRelativeLayout">
```

Image of how it looks [image]

Now if I add a margin of 50dp to the ScrollView, the RelativeLayout matches the height of the scroll view and cuts off the button rather than expanding and allowing for scrolling. [image]

Any ideas on how to fix this? I would like the RelativeLayout to actually wrap to the content and not cut it off.

Comment: I would like to ask you: to what purpose are you nesting a ScrollView inside a RelativeLayout?

Comment: I see these pictures have been taken in the UI Builder portion of Android Studio. What happens when you actually RUN the project? I expect that you will actually be able to scroll, unlike in the UI Builder that Android Studio contains.

Comment: @S.Martell is there an alternative?

Comment: @TheAnonymous010 unfortunately the same problem occurs and I am unable to scroll :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. One of the views within the ScrollView was aligned to the horizontally/vertically center which doesn't make sense in the context of a view that changes it size dynamically. This was causing the RelativeLayout within the ScrollView to simply stay the size of the ScrollView rather than wrapping its content.

If your entire layout is scrollable I would suggest making the base layout a ScrollView rather than a RelativeLayout like I did above.

Comment: Usually ScrollViews and NestedScrollViews are the top parents. Unless they are contained on a small fragment or a ViewPager, having another layout as their parent makes little to no sense.